# Which one is better for a Vaadin application, Tomcat or Jetty?

Tags: tomcat, gwt, jetty, vaadin

I am developing an application using the [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) framework with Maven2. Personally I do not want to go with GAE. I am currently using a Tomcat 6.0 app server for my application. How about Jetty?

- What are the differences between Tomcat in Jetty in terms of setup, performance, stability, etc.?
- Which one is supported by hosting providers?
- Which one is easier to configure?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need self executable then you should use jetty. If you are gonna deploy ur app to a hosting company, probably tomcat will be easier as it will be already there and you need to drop ur war file to the appropriate folder only.

I am not sure if you can run an embedded jetty on all the hosting services because of the limitation of the hosting service jetty may not work.

Comment: it is not actually jetty limitation, it can be the hosting company limitation.

Answer (score 2):

[Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_tomcat) and [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) are quite similar products, with the same kind of feature set. They both implement the Java [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) & [JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) specs, contain a web server, and have decent documentation. Both are open-source, free-of-cost, and popular. They both do the same kind of work, have similar scalability, and are frequently updated. They both work well for Vaadin 6.

Comparing Tomcat and Jetty is like comparing Honda Civic and Toyota Corolla. They are more alike than different. They both contrast with products like [Glassfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) and [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jboss) which are much bigger with many features going well beyond Servlets and web serving.

As mentioned in the other answer, one of the few distinctions between Tomcat and Jetty is that Jetty is designed to be run embedded inside another Java app as well as run by itself. Tomcat in contrast runs only as its own app.

The ramification of this difference, is that when doing Vaadin work in Eclipse, folks commonly use the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (WTP) package of plugins to bridge between Eclipse running as its own app and Tomcat or Jetty running as its own app, and yet talking to each other to make development easier. Other folks prefer not to run WTP, and instead choose to configure Jetty to run within Eclipse, as a part of Eclipse, which is not possible with Tomcat. Each of these approaches have pros and cons, but this is one of the few true differences between Tomcat & Jetty when it comes to doing Vaadin development.